# Custom category collection not rendering correct results in layered navigation and toolbar in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, toolbar

I am displaying a custom product collection in a block that extends the category block.

I have overriden `catalog_category_view` in my custom module.  The custom filter yields renders proper collection in the category page, but the layered navigation and the toolbar doesnot render the proper collection.

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Category\Form" name="custom_category_collection" before=
                "-" template="category/filter.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/namespace/module/Block/Category/Form.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Category;

class Form extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $collection = $this->_catalogLayer->getProductCollection();

        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->where("e.entity_id = 18");
        return $this;
    } 
}
```

Strange thing is, i noticed that the toolbar and layered navigation worked well with the custom collection when the module `CatalogSearch` was disabled. But otherwise, it doesnt work.

Can anyone suggest a solution. Thanks.

Comment: did you get the solution for it ? Please share your answer.

Comment: @Manashvi birla did you get the solution for it ? i have the same problem

Comment: i dnt have any solution yet.!

Answer (score 0):

Please use getSize() function on product collection after your filters

```
$collection->getSize();
```

It calculates all mandatory data for layered and toolbar